# Microsoft Word to Org-mode

Tags: perl, emacs, ms-word, org-mode

I am trying to put the Microsoft Word document in emacs using org-mode.  I have copied the Word Document and pasted in emacs. I like to achieve the headings like 7.1.2.4 in org-mode format.
and then link the TOC to appropriate headings. How I can do that? Any suggestions? Any programming language like Perl has done it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is **ODT2ORG** (https://bitbucket.org/josemaria.alkala/odt2org/wiki/Home) which lets you import odt files in org-mode.

1. Use Openoffice/Libreoffice to produce an .odt from your .doc.
2. Use odt2org to get an .org.

About the headings: I am not entirely sure I understand you.

- there is org-toc.el included in org-mode that provides a seperate buffer with a TOC of your current document (like in Reftex). All the entries there are already links to the individual headings. Also, an exported document will have a TOC included by default without your intervention.
- Orgmode does not support automatically numbered headings (yet). However, if you want to export your document to html, docbook, latex, or pdf, your headings will appear numbered and nested (you can tweak the settings quite a lot).

I doubt that you will get your intended result purely automatically but it should work 70% automatically, especially if you have latex installed and simply want to have a good-looking pdf in the end. Convert doc to odt, convert odt to org, open and type "C-c C-e d".

Comment: Thanks, I will try that when possible. Unfortunately,  I cannot install open office on my system , so I cannot use that. Yes, I was talking about the 'numbered' heading that Microsot Word  generates.  I had hopped for  some sort of Elisp Macro or Programming solution.

Comment: I think there are some converters from doc to odt that work without installing OpenOffice. If you cannot install anything, you could use [http://zamzar.com/] . About the numbered headings: those are automatically created for you when you export the file to html or pdf, they are just not present in the org-buffer itself. But if you really need those numbers in org, you could copy them from your exported file and paste them back into the headings in org. (The exporter will 'count' headings and subheadings for you so you don't lose track.)

Comment: After checking the intertubes, I found this: http://leapon.net/en/mso2ooo-batch-convert-microsoft-office-documents-openoffice-documents

Comment: After checking the intertubes, I found this: http://leapon.net/en/mso2ooo-batch-convert-microsoft-office-documents-openoffice-documents I did not test it but it seems pretty powerful if the description of the author is correct. BTW, I tried the odt2org script and it even recognized the openoffice footnotes correctly (40 pages doc) - I got a very nice pdf via latex without changing anything by hand (including a TOC and numbered headings).

Comment: After a long time, it is still a working solution. Documents without figures and equations (but with headings and even tables). Probably the root of the problem is that it can not communicate well with the recent [olefile](https://www.decalage.info/olefile) package.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:  Save as an HTML file, then use Pandoc to convert the HTML to an .org file.

Answer (score 0):

I've converted loads of Word documents into Org files. It takes minutes to do it by hand.

If you want cross-references, use internal links (4.2 in the current manual).

The * and ** style headings are always likely to be there in Org. Think of the use case where exports are compiled from #+INCLUDEd files, or you have done a selective export using tags. Any kind of single sourcing technology isn't going to display the numbering.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ruby gem which converts doc to md. With pandoc you can convert to org.

https://github.com/benbalter/word-to-markdown