# Conversion of .ppt or .odf files to org-mode format?

Tags: emacs, latex, ms-office, powerpoint, org-mode

I have a number of .ppt files I would like to dump into org-mode format (to export as LaTeX beamer). Is there any (pre-existing) way of automating this process, to any degree? Preferably one that is Linux-friendly?

Comment: Is http://stackoverflow.com/a/6944741/789593 helpful?